# Geocoder search text api is not giving the SpeedLimit

Tags: here-api

API: https://geocoder.cit.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?searchtext=200%20S%20Mathilda%20Sunnyvale%20CA&app_id=DemoAppId01082013GAL&app_code=AJKnXv84fjrb0KIHawS0Tg&gen=8

The mentioned api when tried from custom credentials(trial version) does not return speed limit while same request when tried with demo credentials works fine.

This can be easily reproduced in following url:

https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/geocoder/latitude-longitude-by-free-form-address

Is this by design and is not allowed on trial credentials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [documentation](https://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder/topics/resource-type-response-geocode.html#address) "The SpeedLimit attribute requires authorization and the attribute is not included in LinkInfo if the client application is not authorized to receive this information."